# How to insert a regular expression pattern from resources into a string.Format?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, resources, string-formatting

When generating the JavaScript code that uses a regular expression, I observe problems with inserting the regular expression pattern from a string variable. The content is read from a resource file.

It seems to me that the problem is with backslash interpretation when inserted into the template string using `string.Format`. The JavaScript seems to be fine; however, the regular expression does not match the correct text.

The regular expression pattern defines how a company email should look like, and it is defined in the resource file (that is read into a string variable first). It looks like this: `"\\w+\\.\\w+@company.com"`. It should match users with e-mail like `john.doe@company.com`. If it does not match, the JavaScript code asks for further confirmation.

The same JavaScript (as shown below) worked fine when it was hardwired. The problem is related to the dynamic definition of the JavaScript code.

**Context:** Having the even handler for an asp.net button, I want to add the client side code. The pattern is in the resources because the code should be reused for more companies. The confirmation text is in the resources because of internationalization.

```
    protected void btnSave_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxButton btn = sender as ASPxButton;
        string regex = GetLocalResourceObject("btnSave.RegEx").ToString();
        string txt = GetLocalResourceObject("btnSave.ConfirmText").ToString();
        txt = txt.Replace("\r\n", "\\n");   // must be a single line for JavaScript
        string fo = @"
function(s, e) {{
    var rex = new RegExp('{0}', 'i');
    if (!rex.test(email.GetText()))
        e.processOnServer = confirm('{1}');
}}";
        btn.ClientSideEvents.Click = String.Format(fo, regex, txt);
    }
```

**Update:** The string written into the resource file looks like `\w+\.\w+@company\.com` (single backslashes, the escape of the last dot fixed). When read to a string variable, the backslashes are inside as normal characters. The text retreived from the form is like `jiri.novak@company.com`. The line that creates the regular expression object was changed to `var rex = /^(?:{0})$/i;` as suggested. There was another minor bug that was not shown.

Comment: What does the regex look like when retrieved from the resource file?

Comment: Please share the values of `regex` and `txt` for testing.

Comment: Note that `RegExp#test` in JS will look for partial matches, so `"\\w+\\.\\w+@company.com"` will also match a string like `@#% e.u@company.comherewOW!`. Also, the `.` before `com` matches any char, so it will match, e.g. `e.f@company§com`.

Comment: That said,  try `var rex = /^(?:{0})$/i;` instead of your `var rex = new RegExp('{0}', 'i');` code.

Comment: Or keep `var rex = new RegExp('{0}', 'i');` but use `String.Format(fo, Regex.Escape(regex), txt)` (you will not have to worry about escaping `/` - I forgot to add it when posting the comment above)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the help. Please, copy your comment as the answer to be accepted/closed. What is the `(?:xxx)` does? Is it necessary?

Comment: Sorry,  II'm on the go now. So `var rex = /^(?:{0})$/i;` worked? Note you also need to replace all `/` with `\/` then.

Comment: @pepr: Added. See the note about `/` symbol, it should be escaped in the regex literal  notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you need to pass a literal `\w+\.\w+@company\.com` string. It means that the backslashes must be *literal* backslash symbols, not those backslashes that form *escape sequences* (like `\n` for a newline, `\r` for a carriage return, etc).

So, there are 2 ways to create a regex in JS: a constructor notation (`new RegExp("\\w+\\.\\w+@company\\.com")`) or a regex literal notation (e.g. `/\w+\.\w+@company\.com/`, no additional backslash escaping necessary as the `\` is treated as a literal backslash in the regex literals). Besides, in regex literals, you must escape `/` symbol.

Note you need to match the whole string against the regex, so you need `^` and `$` anchors, too.

Thus, you need

```
var rex = /^(?:{0})$/i;
```

and when passing a `regex`, replace all unescaped `/` with `\/`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for comments. I am aware of regular expression, including the `/` separators to mark the pattern inside as "do not interpret backslash sequences when consuming the source code". I did use the simpler `/^{0}$/i`. Or is the `(?:xxx)` somehow useful here?

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that groups subpatterns. If you pass `one|two` pattern to `/^{0}$/i`, it will become `/^one|two$/i` and it will match any astring starting with `one` or ending with `two`.